# Changing field values selected attributes of shapefile in ArcGIS desktop?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, cursor

I have nine fields in a shapefile and want to use Python to change the values of those fields. The value would be given by the user.

The attributes selected would receive the input value each time the script is run. If the first field is non-zero, it would be compared to the value input and if they are not the same, the values would be compared to the second field. If it doesnot find the value in any of the field, it would append the value to the end.

The table looks like this:

[image]

If the input is 350, then the table should look like this.

[image]

As you can see, I want only the selected rows to be populated with the value. And, the given input may not be received by the same field.

In other words, it should append the given input if it is not present in any of the specified fields.

Comment: `for i in Railroads` will give you `i = 'RR1'`, never `i == 0`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to give a bit more info about what exactly your end result is supposed to look like?  Are you wanting all fields to be populated with the same value?

Comment: So if your `value` is `123`, for the first line you have `RR1` of `555`, but would you then want rows `RR2` through to `RR9` to equal `123`?  Or just `RR2`, `RR3`, `RR4` because they're `0`?

Comment: @Midavalo If my input is 123, as it is not equal to any of the values I have in any of the fields, it would be in the field with the first 0 from left to right. The other 0s on the right would be as it is.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to give a before and after view of what you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a cursor to get the *value* of a field, otherwise you're just referencing the field name.

```
Links_Final = "Links_Final"
Railroads = ('RR1', 'RR2', 'RR3', 'RR4', 'RR5', 'RR6', 'RR7', 'RR8', 'RR9') 

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Links_Final, Railroads) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0] # Will print the value of 'RR1' field
        row[0] = value # Will set the value of 'RR1' field to equal value parameter
        cursor.updateRow(row) # Save the changes
```

**Note** As I don't fully understand your desired result, this is just an **example** of how to use the Update Cursor to get and set values.

Comment: Does this code work on the selected rows or all the rows?

Comment: @pnkjmndhl `row[0]` refers to the first field in your list `RR1`.  `row[1]` refers to `RR2` (your second field), and so on.

Comment: See [UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)